# F# and duck-typing

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, type-inference, duck-typing

Let's say I defined in F# the following two types:

```
type Dog = { DogName:string; Age:int }
type Cat = { CatName:string; Age:int }
```

I was expecting the following method to work for both cats and dogs:

```
let isOld x = x.Age >= 65
```

Actually, what seems to happen  is that `isOld` will only accept cats:

```
let dog = { DogName = "Jackie"; Age = 4 }
let cat = { CatName = "Micky"; Age = 80 }

let isDogOld = isOld dog //error
```

My hopes were that F# would be smart enough to define some kind of "virtual" interface `X` for both cats and dogs so that `isOld` would accept a X as argument, instead of a `Cat`.

This isn't something that F# will in any circumstance handle, am I right? It seems like F# type inference system would not do anything more than what the C# does with `var` typed variables.

Comment: Out of nowhere! It was a typo.

Comment: You're asking for a lot from the compiler, but Google Go does what you want although the function signature wouldn't be implicit, the type signature would.

Comment: What you are asking for is **structural** typing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define an `inline` function with a member constraint, or go the classic route and use an interface (which would probably be preferred in this case).

```
let inline isOld (x:^T) = (^T : (member Age : int) x) >= 65
```

#### EDIT

I just remembered this won't work for record types. Technically their members are fields, although you can amend them with members using `with member ...`. You would have to do that to satisfy an interface anyway.

For reference, here's how you would implement an interface with a record type:

```
type IAging =
  abstract Age : int

type Dog = 
  { DogName : string
    Age : int } 
  interface IAging with
    member this.Age = //could also be `this.Age = this.Age`
      let { DogName = _; Age = age } = this
      age
```

Answer (score 9):

Usually what is meant by F# duck-typing is a compile-time polymorphism. Syntax is a little weirder, but you should be able to work it out from the following example -

```
module DuckTyping

// Demonstrates F#'s compile-time duck-typing.

type RedDuck =
    { Name : string }
    member this.Quack () = "Red"

type BlueDuck =
    { Name : string }
    member this.Quack () = "Blue"

let inline name this =
    (^a : (member Name : string) this)

let inline quack this =
    (^a : (member Quack : unit -> string) this)

let howard = name { RedDuck.Name = "Howard" }
let bob = name { BlueDuck.Name = "Bob" }
let red = quack { RedDuck.Name = "Jim" }
let blue = quack { BlueDuck.Name = "Fred" }
```

Remember, this polymorphism only works at compile-time!

Answer (score 4):

[FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic#fsharpdynamic-) (on nuget) provides a DLR based implementation of the dynamic operator (real dynamic duck typing)

```
let isOld x = x?Age >= 65
```

Comment: It seems to rely on the run-time to do that. What I was looking for at first was a static way to infer this.