# Sub-Records using F#

Tags: function, parameters, f#, record

Assume the following code:

```
type Large = { v1: int; v2: int }
type Small = { v1: int }

let fn (value: Small) = printfn "%d" value.v1
// or
let fn (value: {v1: int}) = printfn "%d" value.v1

let large = { v1 = 5; v2 = 6 }
fn large
```

`Small` is basically a sub-record of `Large`. `fn large` throws an error. Is there any "nice" way how to make it work?

Background:

Often there is a situation where you have a lot of data. You want to pass that data to an unknown function provided from the user as a parameter. The only thing that you know is that the function will need a part of the data. But you do not know which part of the data and you do not know about the `Small` type. You only know about the `Large` type. One option is to send all the data to the unknown function in the form of a `large` record. But I believe that the `fn` function should not accept `Large` data if it uses only small part of it. The `Large` data will just make the `fn` function more difficult to read, understand and unit test. To my opinion the `fn` function should accept only what it needs and nothing else, but up front I do not know which part of the `Large` type the `fn` function will need.

Comment: What do you mean by should ? design, ease of use.. ?

Comment: I think this should explain some of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016087/strange-behavior-of-f-records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Large data will just make the fn function more difficult to read, understand and unit test.

I am not sure if I get the problem correctly. But if the main problem is about readability and test-ability, then maybe just use a conversion function

```
let forgetful (large : Large) = ({v1=large.v1} : Small)
```

then write your function

```
let fn (value: Small) = printfn "%d" value.v1
```

which is readable/testable and get the desire function f by stipulating

```
let f x = fn (forgetful x)
```

which doesnt require testing anymore..

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces might be a closer fit to what you have described in the updated question:

```
type Small =
    abstract v1 : int
type Large =
    inherit Small
    abstract v2 : int

let fn (value: Small) = printfn "%d" value.v1

let large = 
    { new Large with
        member small.v1 = 5
        member large.v2 = 6 }

fn large
```

With interfaces the `Large` type can now be composed from 1 or more `Small` types. Functions can expect only the `Small` type they need, and the caller can simply pass a `Large` type to each function.

Depending on the scenario you might also consider having a `Large` record type that implements one or more `Small` interfaces.

```
type Small = abstract v1 : int
type Large = { v1: int; v2: int } with
    interface Small with member this.v1 = this.v1

let fn (value: Small) = printfn "%d" value.v1

let large = { v1 = 5; v2 = 6 }

fn large
```

Yet another option is to define a union for all the possible `Small` items, and define `Large` as a list:

```
type Item =
    | V1 of int
    | V2 of int

type Large = Item list

let (|Small|) (large:Large) = 
    large |> List.pick (function V1(v1) -> Some(v1)  | _ -> None)

let fn (Small value) = printfn "%d" value

let large = [V1(5);V2(6)]    

fn large
```

[Active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd233248.aspx) can be used to extract `Small` types from the data. An example of this kind of scheme is the [FIX protocol](http://www.fixprotocol.org/) which composes large financial data blocks from small tagged data blocks.

Comment: I have completely rewritten the question to make it more clear. Is your answer still valid?

Comment: But here you assume that you know about the `Small` type. But in reality you do not know about it. Imagine that you have a lot of data and the user picks a few of it and use it (save it etc.) and the rest of the data is lost for ever. So I do not know what `Small` will be - just that it is a sub-data of `Large`.

Comment: @OldrichSvec I've added another option, given your comment above you might want to consider composing `Large` from a list of `Small` types rather than using records

Comment: It looks interesting. I will have to think what are pros and cons of your solution. See my two possible solutions.

Comment: Both of your options also look viable

Answer (score 1):

If you truly dont know beforehand which part of Large fn will use, then you have to give it all. this is the only semantically correct choice.

Now you might be puzzled because you feel that fn does not need all of it, because of the *kind* of function that fn is, and you are just missing some name to give to that class of functions.

One you give a name to this class, you can reduce Large to only the parts that it needs to access, or break fn in a part that is generic, and another tied to your type for that class of functions, like

```
type Large = { v1: int; v2: int }
   with x.AdaptToPrintable() =  x.v1.ToString()
```

and

```
fn x = printfn "%A" x
```

PS : I guess I am confused if your problem lies with the semantic or with the operational aspect of specifying values. If the later, then Phil's answer seem to be the best..

Comment: I would give it a name `postprocess`. It takes all produced data and chooses which is relevant for the user and those data will be saved, send etc. The rest of the data will be ignored and lost. So you are probably correct that you have to send all the data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following:

[Strange behavior of F# records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016087/strange-behavior-of-f-records) :

> It is important to realize that F# does not use structural typing (meaning that you cannot use record with more fields as an argument to a function that takes record with fewer fields). This might be a useful feature, but it does not fit well with .NET type system. This basically means you cannot expect too fancy things - the argument has to be a record of a well known named record type.

nicolas:

> If you truly dont know beforehand which part of Large fn will use, then you have to give it all. this is the only semantically correct choice.

I have come up with two possible solutions:

**Solution 1**

I basically split the user function into two. The nice thing is that `reducedPostprocessFn` accepts only what it needs. This function is therefore easy to reason about and unit test. `postprocessFn` is so short that it is also simple to see what it does. I find this solution similar to active patterns presented by `Phillip Trelford`. I wonder what the advantage of active patterns is?

```
(* simulation *)

type Large = {v1: int; v2: int}

let simulation postprocessFn =
  let large = {v1 = 1; v2 = 2}
  postprocessFn large

(* user *)

let reducedPostprocessFn (v1: int) =
  printfn "%d" v1

let postprocessFn (large: Large) =
  reducedPostprocessFn large.v1

simulation postprocessFn
```

**Solution 2**

This solution uses duck typing but:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx

> Explicit Member Constraint: ... not intended for common use.

[F# and duck-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065939/f-and-duck-typing)

> I just remembered this won't work for record types. Technically their members are fields, although you can amend them with members using with member ....

So I used an ordinary class instead of records. Now I use only one function instead of two but, to be honest, duck typing in F# is just ugly.

```
(* simulation *)

type Large(v1, v2) =
  member o.v1 = v1
  member o.v2 = v2

let simulation postprocessFn =
  let large = Large(1, 2)
  postprocessFn large

(* user 2 *)

let inline postprocessFn small =
  let v = (^a: (member v1: int) small)
  printfn "%d" v

simulation postprocessFn
```