# Strange behavior of F# records

Tags: f#

There is a few cases when F# records behavior is strange to me:

**No warning on ambiguity**

```
type AnotherPerson = {Id: int; Name: string}
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string;}

// F# compiler will use second type without any complains or warnings
let p = {Id = 42; Name = "Foo";}
```

**Warning on records deconstruction instead of records construction**

Instead of getting a warning on records construction in previous case, F# compiler issued a warning on records "deconstruction":

```
// Using Person and AnotherPerson types and "p" from the previous example!
// We'll get a warning here: "The field labels and expected type of this 
// record expression or pattern do not uniquely determine a corresponding record type"
let {Id = id; Name = name} = p
```

Note, that there is no warnings with pattern matching (I suspect thats because patterns are built using "records construction expressions" and not with "records deconstruction expression"):

```
match p with
| {Id = _; Name = "Foo"} -> printfn "case 1"
| {Id = 42; Name = _} -> printfn "case 2"
| _ -> printfn "case 3"
```

**Type inference error with missing field**

F# compiler will choose second type and than will issue an error because Age field is missing!

```
type AnotherPerson = {Id: int; Name: string}
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string; Age: int}

// Error: "No assignment given for field 'Age' of type 'Person'"
let p = {Id = 42; Name = "Foo";}
```

**Ugly syntax for "records deconstruction"**

I asked several collegues of mine a question: "What this code is all about?"

```
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string;}
let p = {Id = 42; Name = "Foo";}

// What will happend here?
let {Id = id; Name = name} = p
```

That was total surprise for everyone that "id" and "name" are actually "lvalues" although they placed at the "right hand side" of the the expression. I understand that this is much more about personal preferences, but for most people seems strange that in one particular case output values are placed at the right side of the expression.

I don't think that all of this are bugs, I suspect that most of this stuff are actually features.
My question is: **is there any rational behind such obscure behavior?**

Answer (score 9):

I think most of your comments are related to the fact that record names become directly available in the namespace where the record is defined - that is, when you define a record `Person` with properties `Name` and `Id`, the names `Name` and `Id` are globally visible. This has both advantages and disadvantages:

- The good thing is that it makes programming easier, because you can just write `{Id=1; Name="bob"}`
- The bad thing is that the names can clash with other record names that are in scope and so if your names are not unique (your first example), you get into troubles.

You can tell the compiler that you want to always explicitly qualify the name using `RequireQualifiedAccess` attribute. This means that you won't be able to write just `Id` or `Name`, but you'll need to always include the type name:

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type AnotherPerson = {Id: int; Name: string}
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string;}

// You have to use `Person.Id` or `AnotherPerson.Id` to determine the record
let p = {Person.Id = 42; Person.Name = "Foo" }
```

This gives you a stricter mode, but it makes programming less convenient. The default (a bit more ambiguous behavior) is already explained by @pad - the compiler will simply pick a name that is defined later in your source. It does this even in the case where it could infer the type by looking at other fields in the expression - simply because looking at other fields would not always work (e.g. when you use the `with` keyword), so it is better to stick to a simple consistent strategy.

As for the pattern matching, I was quite confused when I've seen the syntax for the first time too. I think it is not used very often, but it can be useful.

It is important to realize that F# does not use *structural typing* (meaning that you cannot use record with more fields as an argument to a function that takes record with fewer fields). This might be a useful feature, but it does not fit well with .NET type system. This basically means you cannot expect too fancy things - the argument has to be a record of a well known named record type.

When you write:

```
let {Id = id; Name = name} = p
```

The term *lvalue* refers to the fact that `id` and `name` appear in the *pattern* rather than in an *expression*. The syntax definition in F# tells you something like this:

```
expr := let <pat> = <expr>
      | { id = <expr>; ... }
      | <lots of other expressions>

pat  := id
      | { id = <pat>; ... }
      | <lots of other patterns>
```

So, the left hand side of `=` in `let` is a pattern, while the right hand side is an expression. The two share similar structure in F# - `(x, y)` can be used both to construct and to de-construct a tuple. And the same is the case for records...

Comment: Thanks, Tomas. Its clear that this is a feature but not a bug;) My point is: why we have current behavior? For example, if compiler see two matching record types I'll prefer to see this (at least with warning). And what about section "Type inference error with missing field"? Is it seems reasonable to you?

Comment: @Sergey : Why should type shadowing warrant a warning/error when variable shadowing does not? Indeed, the latter is idiomatic, not surprising...

Comment: @ildjarn: suppose we have large project and someone will add similar record in it. Compiler will choose latest one related to file order in solution explorer. For me its too dangerous. Why *not to issue a warning in this case*? What the benefit of not showing a warning to the user?

Comment: @Sergey : I'm simply saying that it would be inconsistent to warn about shadowing types and not variables.

Comment: @ildjarn In C++ there is more or less the same notion on variable shadowing but type ambiguity is forbidden. Values (by its nature) has narrow scope so such shadowing is OK. But choosing type is more important action (for example, we can choose another method during overload resolution based on record type) so I don't think that consistency is strong argument in this case.

Comment: @Sergey : C++ lets you create UDTs with the same member names, it just doesn't have pattern matching -- if it did, who's to say it wouldn't suffer the same "problem"?

Comment: @ildjarn: I mean that there is a huge difference between value shadowing and type shadowing. And I would like to avoid such shadowing especially in the language with such strict rules that relies on file order.

Comment: I agree with Sergey. The problem is that you are allowed to do `let a = {name = 5}` instead of `let a = Person{name = 5}`. I really find records one of the strangest and worst F# features.

Answer (score 8):

Your examples can be divided into two categories: **record expressions** and **record patterns**. While record expressions *require to declare all fields* and return some expressions, record patterns have *optional fields* and are for the purpose of pattern matching. [The MSDN page on Records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) have two clear sections on them, it may worth a read.

In this example,

```
type AnotherPerson = {Id: int; Name: string}
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string;}

// F# compiler will use second type without any complains or warnings
let p = {Id = 42; Name = "Foo";}
```

the behaviour is clear from the rule stated in [the MSDN page above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx).

> The labels of the most recently declared type take precedence over
>   those of the previously declared type

In the case of pattern matching, you focus on creating some bindings you need. So you can write

```
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string;}
let {Id = id} = p
```

in order to get `id` binding for later use. Pattern matching on let bindings may look a bit weird, but it's very similar to the way you usually pattern match in function parameters:

```
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string;}
let extractName {Name = name} = name
```

I think warnings on your pattern matching examples are justified because the compiler can't guess your intention.

Nevertheless, different records with duplicate fields are not recommended. At least you should use qualified names to avoid confusion:

```
type AnotherPerson = {Id: int; Name: string}
type Person = {Id: int; Name: string; Age: int}

let p = {AnotherPerson.Id = 42; Name = "Foo"}
```

Comment: Thanks, @pad. I understand that current behavior for taking last definition is well-documented. But it still seems weird to me. I prefer to get error or warning in this case. And what about my section called "Type inference error with missing field"? Is it seems reasonable to you?