# Why doesn't type inference determine automatically that property exists on type?

Tags: f#, type-inference

I need to compare objects of different types which I know all have properties Id and Legacy_id. Unfortunately I cannot add interface to them since the types come from database schema. I hoped the following comparer would work:

```
type Comparer<'T >()=
  interface System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<'T> with 
    member this.Equals (o1:'T,o2:'T)=
      o1.Legacy_id=o2.Legacy_id
    member this.GetHashCode(o:'T)=
      o.Id+o.Legacy_id
```

Also I have instantiations of the comparer type with the types. So, theoretically compiler has enough information.

But it gives an error: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

I wonder why F# fails here? Are there any real/theoretical restrictions or it is just not implemented? Such kind of inference could be very useful.

I suspect that an explanation is about F# compiler is only forward walking. The limitation C# doesn't have. That's what error message is complaining about. Is that so?

Comment: This can't be compiled, because any given `'T` is not guaranteed to have a property named `Id`. Here's a thought experiment: what would happen if you instantiated this class as `Comparer<int>`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin But I don't instantiate it as Comparer<int>. So, until I instantiate it with right types compilation could work.

Comment: Still, try to imagine: what do you think should happen if you try `int`?

Comment: This wouldn't work in C# either since `'T` does not have an `Id` property. C#/F# generics are typechecked once and are not expanded based on their usage like C++ templates.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin OK, there will be error.So what?

Comment: @Lee Yes, I know. But C# never had as powerful type inference system as F# does.

Comment: How should the compiler decide to generate an error? On what basis?

Comment: The F# type inference is powerful, but not perfect. One of the things it can't do is infer "pseudo-interfaces" like "all of these classes have an Id attribute". That's partly because it's tied to the .Net type system, which doesn't allow such pseudo-interfaces. But also, the F# compiler wants to make *guarantees* of safety. And just because you don't instantiate `Comparer<int>` *now*, doesn't mean the compiler can know you won't do so in the *future*. Since it can't guarantee that, it can't assume that `'T` will always have an `Id` property.

Comment: However, if you could use a pseudo-property, so that the definition looked something like `type Comparer<'T when 'T : has(.Id)>`, then the compiler *would* be able to guarantee the safety of future instantiations. Unfortunately, because the F# compiler is tied to the .Net type system, that's not yet possible; such pseudo-properties do not currently exist, and are (AFAIK) not likely to exist in the near future.

Comment: @rmunn you can kinda do that with statically resolved constraints. But not with classes.

Comment: I think I've found an answer. It seems possible. It's about duck-typing and compile time polymorphism. Please hold on while I'm trying to apply it to my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065939/f-and-duck-typing

Comment: another name for the stuff: ad-hoc polymorphism

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Member constraints cannot be used on types, which is why you can't do this.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters).

What you could do is create a comparer class that accepts an explicit equality-checking and hash code generation function for a specific type, e.g.

```
type Comparer<'T>(equalityFunc, hashFunc) =
  interface System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<'T> with 
    member this.Equals (o1:'T,o2:'T)=
      equalityFunc o1 o2
    member this.GetHashCode(o:'T)=
      hashFunc o
```

Then you could use an inline function to generate instances of the above for types that match the constraints you wish to impose:

```
let inline id obj =
    ( ^T : (member Id : int) (obj))

let inline legacyId obj =
    ( ^T : (member Legacy_id : int) (obj))

let inline equals o1 o2 =
    id o1 = id o2

let inline hash o =
    id o + legacyId o

let inline createComparer< ^T when ^T : (member Id: int) and ^T : (member Legacy_id : int) >() =
    Comparer< ^T >(equals, hash) :> System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer< ^T >
```

Say you have some type `TestType` that has the two required properties:

```
type TestType =
   member this.Legacy_id = 7
   member this.Id = 9
```

You can then do, for example, `createComparer<TestType>()` to generate an equality comparer appropriate to your type.

Comment: So, generic types in C# are not statically compiled. I was always wondering why it's not possible to do manipulation of types like in C++ is possible. Now it seems I understand. So, having F#'s ^T I may hope to reimplement   Aleksandrescu's template metaprogramming stuff in F# J

Comment: @alehro F#'s statically resolved type parameters are still significantly less flexible than C++ templates.  For example, there is no way to parametrise values as you might with e.g. `template <int N>` however they do permit things like simulating higher kinded polymorphism.

Answer (score 5):

A concise way of getting a comparer for e.g. creating a `HashSet` is:

```
let inline getId o = (^T : (member Id : int) o)
let inline getLegacyId o = (^T : (member Legacy_id : int) o)

let inline legacyComparer< ^T when ^T : (member Id : int) and ^T : (member Legacy_id : int)>() =
    { new System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<'T> with
          member __.GetHashCode o = getId o + getLegacyId o
          member __.Equals(o1, o2) = getLegacyId o1 = getLegacyId o2 }
```

Type inference is about inferring *a* type, not proving that some generic type parameter satisfies arbitrary conditions for all instantiations (see nominal vs. structural type systems). There are many good answers on statically resolved type parameters on SO already.